# Fixed point iteration: finding sufficient conditions

Tags: numerical-methods

1) Suppose it is known that the fpi $x_n :=g(x_{n-1})$ satisfies the estimate $|x_n-\alpha| \leq c|x_{n-1}-\alpha|^2$

a) Show by induction that $c|x_n-\alpha| \leq (c|x_0-\alpha|)^{2^n} $ and give some condition that is sufficient for the convergence of $x_n$ to $\alpha$

Comment: So, where is the inductive argument? They give you the base case.

Comment: This is all, I'm not missing anything

Comment: You just need to prove $$c|x_n-\alpha| <= (c|x_0-\alpha|)^{2^n}$$ for n > 1 using induction. The convergence condition comes from this inequality.